# Django's ManyToManyField automatically adding a symmetric relationship between objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I am trying to code a model that holds a list of references to other objects of
the same class. I am using a ManyToManyField to store those references. For some
reason when I add an element to the many-to-many field of a second element I get
a reciprocal relation added to the first one.

This is the test model that I declared

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    foo = models.ManyToManyField('self', null=True)
```

Then I populated the database using the interactive shell

```
In [1]: from m2m.models import TestModel

In [2]: m1 = TestModel()
In [3]: m1.save()

In [4]: m2 = TestModel()
In [5]: m2.save()
```

I checked that m1's and m2's foo field is empty.

```
In [6]: m1.foo.all()
Out[6]: []
In [7]: m2.foo.all()
Out[7]: []
```

Then I added m2 to m1.foo

```
In [8]: m1.foo.add(m2)
In [9]: m1.foo.all()
Out[9]: [<TestModel: TestModel object>]
```

And here is where I am lost, for some reason that I don't understand when I appended m2 to m1.foo m1 got appended to m2.foo.

```
In [10]: m2.foo.all()
Out[10]: [<TestModel: TestModel object>]

In [11]: m1.id
Out[11]: 1

In [12]: m1.foo.get().id
Out[12]: 2

In [13]: m2.foo.get().id
Out[13]: 1
```

I am not an expert on Django's ORM so I am not fully understanding why this 
relation is being automatically established.

Is there any way to avoid this behaivour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use symmetrical argument of ManyToManyField.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical